# cp does not copy new files of source location (files created after firing cp command)

Tags: linux, shell

I am using the following command to copy contents from a source directory to a destination directory:

```
cp src/* dest
```

However, after evoking this command and while when contents are getting copied, if I create some more files in the src directory , these newly created files are not copied to the dest directory.

Could you please explain the reason behind it? Does `cp` work on something like making account of contents while `cp` is fired and then copying the contents based  in that account keeping and thus ignoring the newly created contents?

Comment: All the important parts of this happen in userspace, not kernelspace

Answer (score 5):

That is because "src/*" is not evaluated (expanded into a list of files) by cp, but by the shell prior to invoking cp.

Answer (score 2):

Andreas is right that `src/*` is expanded by the shell. However, even if you don't specify the wildcard `cp` might still skip your newly created files because there will be a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing) between the `cp` process accessing the directory and you (actually, the process that creates files on your behalf) modifying the directory.

As far as the implementation of [GNU cp](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/copy.c) is concerned, it does get a list of the directory entries before actual copying (see the `copy_dir` function [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/copy.c)).